# Taking JavaScript variables of text and using them as hidden inputs also

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have some JavaScript that populates a modal from different areas of a site. Basically, if you click the button that expands the modal, it will capture all data related to the button pressed.

This works perfectly, but I need to take the text elements that I'm currently using to populate my  classes and also capture them as hidden inputs to pass to an AJAX call.

The JavaScript below takes all text associated with the clicked button and passes it as the h3 class. My console.logs are dumping the values that I need to also have as hidden inputs.

How can I ( at the time of modal expansion) capture these same elements as hidden inputs AND pass them into an AJAX call?

```js
$('.expand-modalForDelete').click(function() {
  var row = $(this).parent()[0],
    allElementsInRow = $(row).find('div'),
    gName = allElementsInRow[0].outerText,
    gColor = allElementsInRow[1].outerText,
    gCategory = allElementsInRow[2].outerText;
    
  gComment = allElementsInRow[3].outerText;

  $('#gName').text(gName);
  $('#gColor').text(gColor);
  $('#gCategory').text(gCategory);
  $('#gComment').text(gComment);
  console.log(gName);
  console.log(gColor);
  console.log(gCategory);
  console.log(gComment);
  UIkit.modal("#modalForDelete").show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modalForDelete" class="uk-modal modalForDelete">
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
    <form id="editModal">
      <div class="uk-width-1-1">
        <div class="uk-width-1-1" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <div class="uk-grid">
            <h4 class="uk-width-4-10 uk-text-muted">Name</h4>
            <h3 id="gName" class="uk-width-4-10"></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-1" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <div class="uk-grid">
            <h4 class="uk-width-4-10 uk-text-muted">Color</h4>
            <h3 id="gColor" class="uk-width-4-10"></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-1" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <div class="uk-grid">
            <h4 class="uk-width-4-10 uk-text-muted">Category:</h4>
            <h3 id="gCategory" class="uk-width-4-10"></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-1" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <div class="uk-grid">
            <h4 class="uk-width-4-10 uk-text-muted">Comment:</h4>
            <h3 id="gComment" class="uk-width-4-10"></h3>
            <span class="edit-comment-icon uk-icon-pencil uk-width-2-10 uk-text-center" data-uk-tooltip="{cls:'edit-tooltip'}" title="Edit"></span>
            <button class="save-comment-button uk-button uk-button-success uk-width-2-10 uk-hidden">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-center">
        <a id="delete-product-list-item" href="" class="uk-icon-button uk-icon-trash-o"></a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

AJAX:

```
data: /* same as $('#gName').text(gName);
  $('#gColor').text(gColor);
  $('#gCategory').text(gCategory);
  $('#gComment').text(gComment);*/
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is - can you not just use the same data in the ajax call as you've already collected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you just need to create an object containing the data, like this...

```
var ajaxData =  {
    color: gColor,
    category: gCategory,
    comment: gComment
};
```

Then pass that as your data object in the Ajax call...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your-url",
    data: ajaxData
});
```

As for your question about the colour name & number being in the same string, you can split them like this...

```
var value = "112 - Brown";

// Split the string...  (use split("/") if it's a forward-slash)
val1 = val1.split(" - ");

var colorNum = val1[0];
var colorName = val1[1];
```

Comment: Ok so it doesn't have to be a hidden input since it's already captured I guess? So my form around the modal, I can just keep the submit button there and if it's submitted I'll pass the data like I usually would in ajax

Comment: As long as you have populated inputs in the form then the data will be passed, yes.  It's just a case of deciding which is the most appropriate solution for you.

Comment: Well that was my confusion. NOrmally I would have inputs, but here the text needed is a static header, which is why I'm grabbing the text of it as an ID. So either way, I'm getting the data I need

Comment: Hidden fields is a simpler approach, if you already have a form that you submit, and if you have no other reason to look at using Ajax.

Comment: Gotcha, well thank you I think this will work, thanks! Also, if my color field returns "112 - Brown" or "112/Brown", is there a way to split those by the /,- and get the first as colorNum and 2nd as colorName?

Comment: Sure - I'll add something into the answer.

Comment: I've added an example.  Out of curiosity, why did you give 2 examples?  Is it not definite how the string will be formatted?

Comment: Good question haha. yes it is but I believe that one of my fields will always be a - and the other will always be a / , but once I know I'd like to add that in there so I was trying to future proof it a bit

Comment: No worries - glad it helped :)